# Как сохранять картинки в excel файл на python?

Tags: python

Столкнулся с проблемой - есть excel таблица, в ней есть два изображения, и есть программа на python в которой эта таблица редактируется и сохраняется в папку под другим названием, так вот в новом файле этих картинок нету. Можно ли как-то эти картинки вставлять в новый файл или сохранять картинки при переносе. Использовал openpyxl, но можно код на любой библиотеке.

Comment: Добавте ваш код прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Мне кажется он особого смысла не имеет

Comment: Да и можно использовать любую библиотеку на python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с использованием [xlwings](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html)

```
import xlwings as xw

fn = r'D:\temp\Book1.xlsx'

wb = xw.Book(fn)

sh = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

sh.range('A2').value *= 10

wb.save()

# закрыть Excel файл (сам MS Excel при этом не закрывается)    
wb.close()
```

`xlwings` откроет excel файл в MS Excel (соответственно на Linux это работать не будет). Все манипуляции происходят при открытом в MS Excel файле.

[OpenPyxl не умеет сохранять картинки после правки существующего документа](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook):

> Warning
>
> openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file
>   so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are
>   opened and saved with the same name.

Comment: А как сохранить в другой файл?

Comment: @nikita456, wb.save(filename)